# How to run a pre-trained model on tensorflow attention_ocr?

Tags: tensorflow, inference, pre-trained-model

I have managed to train [attention_ocr](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/attention_ocr) on my data, and I am now trying to do an inference run (tensorflow version 1.2.1).

I use the following code based on what is mentioned on the git README to use a pre-trained model, but I always get a list of repeating characters, that changes on each run (like [38,38,38...] ). This is obviously wrong as according to the evaluation on a test set during training, I should have a character accuracy of above 90%!

Has anybody tried this before? Or can somebody provide me with some hints on fixing it?

```
images_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, height, width, channels])
images_actual_data = cv2.imread(imageFname)
images_actual_data = cv2.cvtColor(images_actual_data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# some range normalization that is also done for training data
images_actual_data = images_actual_data.astype('float32')
images_actual_data -= images_actual_data.min()
images_actual_data /= images_actual_data.max()
images_actual_data -= 0.5
images_actual_data *= 2.5


model = common_flags.create_model(69,23,1,68) # based on the trained model
endpoints = model.create_base(images_placeholder, labels_one_hot=None)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_fn = model.create_init_fn_to_restore('/path-to-trained-models/model.ckpt-1126202', '')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) # tried to run sess.run(init_fn) here, but it fails
    predictions = sess.run(endpoints.predicted_chars, feed_dict={images_placeholder:images_actual_data.reshape(1,imHeight,imWidth,imChannel)})
    print predictions
```

Answer (score 2):

I kind of made it work. I was not properly running things in the session.
Anyway, adding the following line before the running for predictions, solved the problem:

```
init_fn(sess)
```

It's apparently not the most optimal way of running the pre-trained model (on the git page [serving infrastructure](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_basic) is recommended), but works fine for me for debugging purposes for now.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the range normalization part is not correct. During a training the model [uses](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/3eba37c/attention_ocr/python/data_provider.py#L133) [tf.image.convert_image_dtype](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/convert_image_dtype). So please try to replace:

```
images_actual_data -= images_actual_data.min()
images_actual_data /= images_actual_data.max()
```

with

```
images_actual_data /= 255.0
```

Comment: Thank Alexander. I did that and it does not change anything. It's suspiciously strange that upon each run, it produces a different output. Do I need to change something somewhere else? like in common_flags.py or so?

Comment: Ok, it looks like something is broken. I'll take a closer look https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2137

Comment: But it finally worked for me. I was making a mistake in running in the session (I answered my question below)